# What constitutes a 'Wonderful Word'?

Tags: android, classic-words

I'm playing 'Classic Words' on Android which recently underwent a major overhaul. One of the new features that has appeared whilst playing is the addition of a 'Wonderful Word' mechanic which allows me to share a word. In this example, I played 'JOE' on a triple-word score, earning 30 points:

[image: 'Wonderful Word' popup]
<sup>[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNDvj.png)</sup>

My question is, what causes the 'Wonderful word' popup? Is it

- Using a less-known/underused word?
- Playing over a triple-word score?
- Scoring greater than a certain amount?
- Something else entirely?

Comment: I've score 36 points on one word and haven't gotten the pop up.  When was your app updated?  The Google Play store says it was last updated in June.  I"m wondering if its different for some devices?

Comment: @Tim - According to my Google Play it's [Dec 12 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPKDS.jpg)

Comment: Definitely not the case for me.  My Samsung Galaxy S6 shows June 14, 2016 with a version number of 1.9.6.  So does my Android tablet.  That explains why I can't replicate this.  I wonder if its a regional thing.

Comment: @Tim mayhaps, or potentially compatibility? I've heard of Play Store hiding apps that won't run on a device, but specific versions seems a bit odd. I've got an HTC One M8 here.

Comment: Do you think that there's something even better than a "wonderful"?

Comment: @pinckerman not sure. Haven't gotten over 50 since the update but under that it's been 'wonderful' words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent a mail to the developer of the game to ask how this message is triggered. Here is what he answered about this feature:

> If you score (in average, based on past stats), less than 0.3 bingos per game, a "wonderful move" is triggered whenever you score more than 30 points.
>   Otherwise, you are considered an experienced player, and you need to score more than 50 points to trigger the pop-up.

So it seems you got the pop-up there because you scored exactly 30 points with the word 'JOE', and you have an average of bingos per game below 0.3.

Comment: I did the same thing, his response was "In a nutshell, a wonder word is a word which score is far above your usual average score."